# Label axis on pandas group by plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting a pandas dataframe with structure similar to

```
index groupcol value
1    A          10
2    B          12
3    C          10
4    A          10
5    C          17
6    A          11
7    B          15
```

with

```
df.groupby([df.index,'groupcol']).mean()['value'].unstack().plot(subplots=True, layout=(3,1))
```

So I get a row of three graphs. How can I add a general x and y labels to the entire plot and not to the individual graphs?

Comment: `ValueError: Layout of 3x1 must be larger than required size 4`